# Entity Framework One to Many with no Collection navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework with Fluent Configuration, I have a `LeaseTrackingType` entity which has a one to many relationship with `LeaseTracking`. Where each lease tracking has a lease tracking type.

However from a code point of view it doesn't really make sense to have a LeaseTrackings collection. Like you are never going to use this navigation property.

**Question: How do I model the one to many relationship without LeaseTrackings collection navigation property?**

Entities:

```
 public class LeaseTracking
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LeaseTrackingTypeId { get; set; }
    public LeaseTrackingType LeaseTrackingType { get; set; }
 }

 public class LeaseTrackingType
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public virtual Collection<LeaseTracking> LeaseTrackings { get; set;}
 }
```

And mapping configuration:

```
    public class LeaseTrackingConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<LeaseTracking>
    {
        public LeaseTrackingConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("LeaseTracking");

            Property(entity => entity.Id);
            HasRequired(entity => entity.LeaseTrackingType)
                .WithMany(entity => entity.LeaseTrackings)
                .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.LeaseTrackingTypeId);
        }
    }

    public class LeaseTrackingTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<LeaseTrackingType>
    {
        public LeaseTrackingTypeConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("LeaseTrackingType");

            Property(entity => entity.Id);
            Property(entity => entity.Name).;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the constructor don't point it out in `WithMany` function and get rid of the `virtual Collection` in `LeaseTrackingType` class

```
  public LeaseTrackingConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("LeaseTracking");

            Property(entity => entity.Id);
            HasRequired(entity => entity.LeaseTrackingType)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(entity => entity.LeaseTrackingTypeId);
        }
```